# Sampling and probability generating functions - reference wanted

Tags: reference-request, probability-distributions

Suppose I have a huge (effectively infinite) population of widgets.  The number of widgets that are broken is given by a random variable $X$, whose probability generating function is $p(z) = E(z^X)$.

Now suppose I look at a proportion $\theta$ ($0 \le \theta \le 1$) of the population.  Let $Y$ be the random variable of the number of broken widgets in this proportion.  Then it is easily shown that the probability generating function for $Y$ is $p(1-\theta(1-z))$.

What is a book that contains this fact so that I can reference it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized that my desired result follows from the second bullet point of this section from wikipedia.  Presumably this can be found in any book on probabilty generating functions, so I guess I'll do a literature search.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function#Functions_of_independent_random_variables